# While running on device Screens doesn't comes Fill screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have run an application in iPhone 5 device it doesn't comes in full screen. remaining top and bottom comes in black color.
In simulator it is working fine.

[image]

**Edit :**

I he used this side menu, [RESidemenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/residemenu)
While using this having the problem with the window. The window is resizing.
I am using Xcode 6.1

Comment: @AshishKakkad: not working.

Comment: @AshishKakkad: I am using Xcode 6.1 .

Comment: Try to add constraints.

Comment: Did you set autoresizing?

Comment: @Ritu: I set auto resize, I think the window is resized.

Comment: How are you adding the window? You should add like :UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

Comment: Did you check the sample app of RESideMenu? This is working fine with 4-inch screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must have your **LaunchScreen.xib** missing or deleted. Add your **LaunchScreen.xib** or **Default-568h@2x.png** to your project and set it to the **Asset Catlog**.

Comment: I have added ' Default-568h@2x.png ' . working fine thanks :)